# jquery ui messing up tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I add Jquery ui to my bootstrap page it messes up the tool tips on the navbar.
[page with jquery ui](http://www.thewhateverclub.altervista.org/index.php?page=about)
[page without jquery ui](http://www.thewhateverclub.altervista.org/home.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that jquery ui's [tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) is the same as bootsrap function `tooltip()` I fixed it by doing this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
<script>$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);</script>
//then import bootstrap
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```